# How to solve $\ln x+x=1$

Tags: contest-math

How can I solve this equation:

$$\ln x+x=1$$

We had it on a local Olympiad math contest problem.

Comment: On a related note, see the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 13):

$1$ is a solution, just substitute and check.

$x+\log(x)$ is strictly increasing, hence 1 to 1. Thus, $x=1$ is the only solution for the equation

Comment: thanks, did you ever have math contest training?

Comment: @user144251 No, and I actually consider myself not good at all in hard math contests such as IMO

Comment: @user144251 See the book " The Art and Craft of Problem solving"

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it!

Answer (score 5):

Intuitively
\begin{align}
\ln x+x&=1\\
\ln x+x\ln e&=1\\
\ln x+\ln e^x&=1\\
\ln (xe^x)&=1\\
xe^x&=e^1\\
xe^x&=1\cdot e^1
\end{align}
By comparing LHS and RHS, we will obtain $x=1$.

Comment: That was so obvious!! DId you had a formal maths contest training?

Comment: @user144251 No! Why did you ask that?

Comment: Because I want to participate in an IMO and I want some advice!

Comment: @user144251 "That was so obvious!!". Is that a compliment or what?

Answer (score 4):

$$\ln x+x=1\implies xe^x = e$$

In other words we need to find a root of $f(x)=xe^x - e$

This function is increasing for $x\gt-1$ thus will have at most one solution in $(-1,\infty)$.

Also since $e^x\gt0$ we must have $x\gt0$.

Now it is easy to see that the one root we need is $x=1$